# Powershell: The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered

Tags: powershell, batch-file, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to run a PowerShell script from a windows batch file. This is a SharePoint related script that uses `Import-SPData`.

This works without any issue when using `USERA`'s login. However, if I try to run the same batch file from `USERB`'s login, I get the error below:

```
c:\PS>ExecMyPowershellScript.bat

c:\PS>C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -psconsolefile "
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\P
OWERSHELL\Registration\psconsole.psc1" -command "c:\ps\MyPSScript.ps1"

The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not regis
tered.
Import-SPData : Cannot access the local farm. Verify that the local farm is pro
perly configured, currently available, and that you have the appropriate permis
sions to access the database before trying again.
At C:\ps\Run_MyPSScript.ps1:5 char:18

...
```

I made sure that `USERB` has permissions to the `bat` and the `ps1` files.

I am using `PowerShell` version 2 and `SharePoint Server 2010`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to get this to work.

According to Microsoft:

> In order to use Windows PowerShell for SharePoint 2010 Products, a
>   user must be a member of the **SharePoint_Shell_Access** role on the
>   configuration database and a member of the **WSS_ADMIN_WPG** local group
>   on the computer where SharePoint 2010 Products is installed.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607596%28v=office.14%29.aspx

To do this:

- Open the SharePoint management shell (run as administrator if you have User Account Control activated)
- Add `SharePoint_Shell_Access` role to USERB for the SharePoint configuration database.

Can use the following PowerShell code to do this:

```
$dbs = Get-SPDatabase; foreach($d in $dbs) {If($d.name.contains("SharePoint_Config")){Add-SPShellAdmin "domain\USERB" -database $d}}
```

- Make sure the SharePoint site collection and document library/list (if any) also have the proper permissions for `USERB`

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint is a beast to deal with.  I would supsect UserB doesnt the proper sharepoint permissions and/or access to the content database

I would compare the permission for UserA and UserB at the Windows, Sharepoint, and DB level to look for differences.